# KDB/q orderbook add rows

Tags: addition, kdb, orderbook

In a table I try to bring together the rows that have the same price by adding the quantities for an order book
all_order_ask:([]ask:();ask_qty:();exchange_name:())
Keep the same ask but when it's the same price add the quantities

Comment: The simple approach is something like `select sum ask_qty by ask from all_order_ask` but this leaves a lot of questions: how do you want the resulting table to be ordered? What do you plan to do when there's more than one exchange quoting at a given price, show the first, last, all of them? Assuming your ask prices are floats you will have to manage the fact that there will be float precision issues so two floats that appear to be the "same" may not be the same and so they won't group properly.

Comment: Do you know how can i combine symbol 
Like if exchange_name:() is Ftx and the second Kraken 
When i combine them i ll get `FtxKraken a new symbol
Thks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your followup question: combining the exchange names would be like this:

```
select sum ask_qty,raze string exchange_name by ask from all_order_ask
```

assuming that `exchange_name` values are symbols...if they're already strings then you only need to `raze`.

I'll highlight again some caveats from my earlier comment:

```
this leaves a lot of questions: how do you want the resulting table to be ordered? Assuming your ask prices are floats you will have to manage the fact that there will be float precision issues so two floats that appear to be the "same" may not be the same and so they won't group properly
```

Comment: Thanks You for all A last question about this subject , i want to do a if like 
If ftx and ftx to dont get "FtxFtx" 
I am starting on kdb 
Thanks for everythings

Comment: You could use `distinct` to get only the unique ones. So `select sum ask_qty,raze string distinct exchange_name by ask from all_order_ask`

Comment: The fact is that command return a Dict and then i can't combine ask and bid in the same table
Do you Know a solution 
thanks

Comment: It's a keyed table (which is implemented like a dictionary and has the same datatype). You can unkey the keyed table using `0!select .....`

Comment: Is there a way to sort by ask while doing this operation

Comment: I don't know why but it messed me up my table